# How do I get 3 horizontal divs to stack in different vertical order or flow when browser width decreases?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 divs in a horizontal row in my footer. I'm using the bootstrap grid.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 div1">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 div2">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 div3">
```

So that they appear in this sequence

```
+------+------+------+
| div1 | div2 | div3 |
+------+------+------+
```

When the browser width decreases to a certain width suppose 600px, I want the 3 divs to stack vertically in a single column in the following sequence.

```
+------+
| div1 |
+------+
| div3 |
+------+
| div2 |
+------+
```

How can I achieve that using CSS?

Comment: Do you need a breakpoint at 600px? It can be done but this is not a default breakpoint for Bootstrap.

Comment: not really. that was just an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use push and pull method. Also remove the `col-xs-6` class to achieve the single column layout on mobile views.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-sm-4">div1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">div3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">div2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class col-xs- applies to screen widths <768px.
If the divs need to stack vertically for mobile views, change this class to 'col-xs-12'
This will make them take 100% width and align vertically one below the other.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it using CSS like this.

say on full screen the css will be

```
.div1, .div2, .div3{
          float: left;
          width : 33%;
    }
```

using css media query

```
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .div1, .div2, .div3{
          width : 100%;
    }
 }
```

now at 600px width or less the divs will be width 100% and they will be shown vertically

in bootsrap you do not need anything, this option is included by default you just need to remove col-xs-6 class from divs